# mysql:how to get 0 when using group by and result doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

this is table test's data:

```
time       | type 
2017-11-01 | a 
2017-11-01 | a 
2017-11-01 | a 
2017-11-01 | b 
2017-11-02 | a 
2017-11-02 | b 
2017-11-02 | b 
2017-11-02 | b 
2017-11-02 | c 
2017-11-03 | a 
2017-11-03 | a
```

how to get the result:

```
time       | type | count(*)
2017-11-01 | a    | 3
2017-11-01 | b    | 1
2017-11-01 | c    | 0
2017-11-02 | a    | 1
2017-11-02 | b    | 3
2017-11-02 | c    | 1
2017-11-03 | a    | 2
2017-11-03 | b    | 0
2017-11-03 | c    | 0
```

I tried to use group by and ifnull, but it is not working. I can't get 0 from the data. Maybe 'join' can work, but how to edit the sql?

Comment: Is the value for type always a, b or c?

Comment: no~ maybe there are other value like d,e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cross join all distinct types to all distinct dates (a cartesian product)

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select distinct type,t1.dt from t
    -> cross join (select distinct dt from t) t1;
+------+------------+
| type | dt         |
+------+------------+
| a    | 2017-11-01 |
| b    | 2017-11-01 |
| c    | 2017-11-01 |
| a    | 2017-11-02 |
| b    | 2017-11-02 |
| c    | 2017-11-02 |
| a    | 2017-11-03 |
| b    | 2017-11-03 |
| c    | 2017-11-03 |
+------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And then left join

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select s.type,s.dt,ifnull(u.obs,0) obs
    -> from
    -> (
    -> select distinct type,t1.dt from t
    -> cross join (select distinct dt from t) t1
    -> ) s
    -> left join
    -> (select type,dt, count(*) obs from t group by type,dt) u on u.type = s.type and u.dt = s.dt ;
+------+------------+-----+
| type | dt         | obs |
+------+------------+-----+
| a    | 2017-11-01 |   3 |
| b    | 2017-11-01 |   1 |
| c    | 2017-11-01 |   0 |
| a    | 2017-11-02 |   1 |
| b    | 2017-11-02 |   3 |
| c    | 2017-11-02 |   1 |
| a    | 2017-11-03 |   2 |
| b    | 2017-11-03 |   0 |
| c    | 2017-11-03 |   0 |
+------+------------+-----+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

note this only works if you are only interested in dates where there is some activity - if not think about building a calander table and use that in the sub query

Comment: it works! Thank u very much! I tried many times on my data in accordance with your method because my data is actually very complicated, and finally succeeded.